# Calculate function values of a interval

Tags: matlab

I'm new to Matlab, and I have a question.

So I have the following task:

To calculate function values on the segment with N points, and which have equal interval from each other.

[image]

I wrote the following code to calculate values for this function.
This is the code:

```
N=8;
x1=-pi;
x2=pi;
x=(x1:x2);
y=power(x,2).*log(power(x,2).+1)+x(sinh(x).;
```

After compiling, I receive such error:

```
Error: File: lab2.m Line: 49 Column: 30
Invalid use of operator.
```

What am I doing wrong?
Every help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the code below

```
N = 8;
x1 = -pi;
x2 = pi;
x = linspace(x1,x2,N);
y = power(x,2).*log(power(x,2)+1)+x.*sin(x);
```

where

- `linspace` creates linearly spaced points within interval `[x1,x2]`
- for the last term you should have `x.*sin(x)`, since yours has syntax error by ending the command with `.` and missing the element-wise product `.*` between `x` and `sin(x)`